# Writing typescript modules and testing with Karma

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I am struggling to find a nice way to write typescript modules, output it in a sensible way and test with Karma as it wants global instances and doesn't support module loading out of the box.

So I cannot write something as a module and consume it in Karma without first wrapping it in wepback/browserify etc which bloats the output quite a lot.

I have tried using the typescript pre-processor and that seemed more for writing your tests in ts, rather than consuming ts files as dependencies. I also tried the requirejs karma module but for some reason it constantly failed to resolve the dependencies so that would not work.

So has anyone got a workflow that works?

Comment: While not Karma-specific, I might recommend using internal modules, aka _namespaces_ if possible for Typescript projects. It saves a lot of headache and overhead from using external modules and a module loading system.

Comment: Originally I did try using that approach before the ES6 module syntax, but it just ended up with overly verbose syntax a lot of the time. With ES6 module syntax everything works far better just being top level classes, i.e `import {foo} from "bar"`